# Internal CSS using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good Day!!!

I am trying to add the `css using jquery`. when i viewing the code using firebug. It looks like in inline css format. But i want to load the internal css property using jquery.
Is it possible to add the internal css using jquery.

```
 $('selector').css('color','#fff');
```

It appear like For example

```
<p style="color:#fff"></p>
```

I want to load as with

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
color:#fff;
}
</style>
```

Not sure, how to do it any one review and advise.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, just append a style tag to the head:

```
$("head").append('<style type="text/css">p {color:#fff;}</style>');
```

see example here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4pna/)

Answer (score 1):

you can define classes (or ids) earlier in head or in external css file and than add this class using jquery

```
$('p').addClass('my-style');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to append the style to the head like this

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
$(headID).append('<style type="text/css">p { color:#fff; } </style>');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add style by jquery it will be for particular id or class.
so it will be display in HTML as inline css.